# Random walk with exponential decay

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, random-walks

A problem which arises in learning algorithms is $$x_{k+1}= \alpha x_k + \beta e_k$$
where $x_k$ is the scalar state variable at time $k$ and $e_k$ is an independent $\mathrm{Normal}(0,1)$ excitation sample.
The parameters are $\alpha < 1$, an exponential decay factor, and $\beta < \alpha $ which controls the excitation level.  The task is to find the asymptotic distribution of $x_k$ in the limit $k \rightarrow \infty$ and all of its moments.
This problem is clearly related to a random walk but I can find nothing on the internet.

Comment: Write it as $x_{k+1} = \alpha x_k + \beta e_k = \alpha(\alpha x_{k-1} + \beta e_{k-1}) + \beta e_k = \ldots$. In the limit it is a simple sum of idendent normal distributed r.v., since $\alpha^k \to 0$.  There is no random walk.

Comment: This problem does have an easy Gaussian solution, but I had managed to lose a power of $x$ in simplifying and writing it out.  The more difficult one is $$w_k+1 =

Answer (score 1):

For completeness: Using the recursion we get
$$x_k = \alpha^k x_0 + \beta \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^{i-1} e_{k-i}, k \in \mathbb{N}.$$
Now if $|\alpha| < 1$ then $\alpha^k x_0 \to 0$ a.e. and by independence $\beta \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^{i-1} e_{k-i} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\beta^2 \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^{2(i-1)})$. It follows that $x_k \to \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{\alpha^2 \beta^2}{1-\alpha^2})$ weakly. Of course the moments of the normal distribution are well known.

Comment: There is a more difficult problem involving Chi squared's rather than Normal excitation which I maybe should have posed.  This is $$x_{k+1} = \alpha x_k - \beta e_k^2 x_k $$ where $e_k$ is Normal(0,1)

Comment: You should ask this in a new question. Are you sure that the recursion is $x_{k+1} = \alpha x_k - \beta e_k^2 x_k$ (a completely different problem (and not $x_{k+1} = \alpha x_k - \beta e_k^2$)?

Comment: I'm trying to solve a state space stochastic gradient descent vector algorithm in its principle components directions as a collection of scalar problems.  The covariance of the solution is previously approximately known for small $\beta$.  I'll recheck and repost a new problem.